# Spring security no longer redirects to login page after upgrade to from Spring Boot 1.5-2,Spring Security 4-5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've got an OAUTH2 app where the oauth2 endpoints are secured by Spring Security, so some pages are protected by a form based login.

Previously if I hit one of these URLs, I was redirected, correctly, to the login page.

I've just upgraded from Spring Boot 1.5.16 to Spring Boot 2.0.6. resulting in an upgrade via dependencies of Spring Security from 4.2.8 to 5.0.9

Now if I hit a URL where I'm not logged in I just get a page like this served up:

```
<oauth>
  <error_description>
    Full authentication is required to access this resource
  </error_description>
  <error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

What's more if I try and hit the login page I'm not authorized to that. Has anyone got any idea about what the cause of this is ? Filter order possibly ?

This is what my security config looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, Environment environment) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.environment = environment;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().
                headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/logout", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

and this is the filter chain that gets created:

```
2018-10-19 15:22:10.865  INFO 19012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@737f44b6, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@61f7a8e9, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@139be706, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@60b40eca, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@7467a12, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4fd13263, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1d003890, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6e762f08, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@13f07542, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2e2ecd3a, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@65db717c]
2018-10-19 15:22:10.880  INFO 19012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$NotOAuthRequestMatcher@4432df93, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@c48f5fc, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@731455ec, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@67e583c6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7bc67409, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@4c112545, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@16762cc2, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5dc67679, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5473e34c, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4e9d0777, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@750210bc, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@d7ab665]
2018-10-19 15:22:10.895  INFO 19012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/login'], Ant [pattern='/logout'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/authorize'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/confirm_access']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@22671580, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@412e0841, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@60f6611f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@24ec00c6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1531681a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@242e419a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@77833299, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2ea3b229, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@38fd683f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7e4364ca, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@63dad600]
201
```

Comment: did you go through the migration guide(s)? (Spring Boot)[https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide] & (Spring Security)[https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0#migrating-from-1x-to-20]

Comment: Yes, nothing stood out.

Comment: I'd review this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0#security-auto-configuration Essentially any security you were relying on by Boot is no longer available in 2.x.

Comment: It turned out to be be filter order.

Comment: @PaulNUK Hi. Sorry, but I was not able to figure out the solution for the above-mentioned issue. Can you please elaborate as I am facing the same issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This Works for Me

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers("/db*/**").fullyAuthenticated().
            antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll().
            and().formLogin().  //login configuration
            loginPage("/index.jsf?faces-redirect=true");
        }
    }
```

and at the url you have to give localhost:8080/db/ and it will automatically redirected to your index page